# How to create JAVASCRIPT ARRAY from external file JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, getjson

What is the best way to create javascript array from json file?
I have four empty JavaScript array that I would like to populate with data imported from a json file.

```
var firstname = new Array();
var address= new Array();
var city = new Array();
```

File Json : "file.json"

```
[
{"name ": "John", "address": "350 Fifth Avenue", "city ": "New York"},
{"name ": "Mark", "address": "1101 Arch St", "city ": "Philadelphia"},
{"name ": "Jack", "address": "60th Street", "city ": "Chicago"}
]
```

I try:

```
$.getJSON('file.json',function (data) {   

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        firstname.push.apply( firstname, data[i].firstname );
        address.push.apply( address, data[i].address );
        city.push.apply( city, data[i].city );
    }

});
```

but arrays are still empty.
Thanks in advance

================================ SOLVED ===============================

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'file.json',
    data: "",
    accepts:'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            firstname.push( data[i].firstname );
            address.push( data[i].address );
            city.push( data[i].city );
        }
    }
})
// Get arrays outside callback function
console.log('result: '+firstname.length); // result: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two or three problems.

### Your JSON is invalid.

Remove the quotes from around the outside of it.

Seriously consider giving is a `.json` file extension, then you are more likely to get the right MIME type for JSON. (JSON data files are not JavaScript programs).

---

File Json : "data.json"

```
[
{"name ": "John", "address": "350 Fifth Avenue", "city ": "New York"},
{"name ": "Mark", "address": "1101 Arch St", "city ": "Philadelphia"},
{"name ": "Jack", "address": "60th Street", "city ": "Chicago"}
]
```

---

### You are accessing your data in the wrong order

This is overly complicated and is accessing properties in the wrong order.

```
name.push.apply(name, data.name[i]);
```

Forget about using `apply`. You don't need it.

Then note that your JSON array contains the objects, not the other way around. You need to access the array index before the property name:

```
name.push(data[i].name);
```

---

### Remember the A in Ajax

Finally - your code doesn't show how you are testing the result. Remember that Ajax is asynchronous, so that if you examine the values of your arrays outside the callback function, they might not have been populated yet.

Comment: His AJAX is fine, q.v. [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-getjson.htm) which presumably runs OK.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen — That doesn't seem to have anything to do with any of the points I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. I really appreciate your answer, very detailed and in particular the last point. **How can I use arrays outside the callback function?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have the order wrong, `data` is the array so it's not

```
data.name[i]
```

but

```
data[i].name
```

and removing the strange `apply` it would be

```
$.getJSON('json.js',function (data) {   
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        name.push( data[i].name );
        address.push( data[i].address );
        city.push( data[i].city );
    }
});
```

Also note that `name` is a bad choice for a variable name in the global context.

Comment: Thank you @adameo, and I apologize for the distraction. I corrected the code as you reported but arrays continue to be empty